# JavaFX getting input from a textfield

Tags: java

I have just started learning java fx and I am trying to get user input from two text field. Once they click the button this will be displayed on a console.
However, I am keep getting an error and cannot figure out why. 
I have assigned the 'handle' function using Scenebuilder, the error is pointing at the method.

Main Class:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Controller:

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Controller {
public TextField userField;
public TextField passField;
public Button logButton;

public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    String username = userField.getText();
    String passw = passField.getText();
    System.out.printf("Logged in as %s %s", username, passw);

}

}
```

Comment: Can u please post the exact error message?

Answer (score 2):

although you didn't show the error, but i think it's because you didn't annotate the fields `userField` and `passwordField` with `@FXML` annotation

by this annotation you tie the fields in the controller with fields in the fxml

so to solve this problem let's do the following simple steps

```
public class Controller implements Initializable{

@FXML
private TextField userField;
@FXML
private TextField passField;
@FXML
private Button logButton;

private void handle(ActionEvent event)
{
    System.out.println(userField.getText());
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
{
    logButton.setOnAction(this::handle);
}}
```

and in the scene builder follow this image [image: scene builder image]

try this,and if you still have problems just let a comment (:

Comment: now it comes up with an error on line: Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));  ///////////




Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#handle', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
/C:/Users/Kris/IdeaProjects/Calculator/out/production/Calculator/sample/sample.fxml:11

Comment: Solved it needed to put @FXML where the handle method is. Thanks for the response, really helped

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Scene Builder, you should use the sample controller skeleton: Under View, select Use Sample Controller Skeleton. Also, specify the "On Action" for the text field. Scene Builder will dot the i's and cross the t's for you.